# Visual Studio & Git resetting to an earlier commit

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, reset

I'm stuck on a tricky issue around VS/git.

The latest committed version is missing some files and I cleverly did some commits before they disappeared.
So now I'm trying to reset to an earlier commit and work on those "missing" files.

When I open the commit I want, from the "History" view in the "Team Explorer", I can see under "Changes" the files I want with "[add]" written behind them.
So far, so good - that is exactly what I want to do, but no matter if I reset soft or hard, these files never find their way into the solution explorer. But I can open them from the "Changes" section, so clearly they are there and still associated with the commit.

I'm not sure if anybody has encountered anything like this, but any help in getting those files from "Changes" to the "Solution Explorer" would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Sven

Comment: Welcome to SO. What happens if you run `git checkout that-revision-where-the-files-are`? They are there, right?

Comment: You're using VS, so this advice isn't very useful, but: you generally don't want to use `git reset` here at all. You want to *explore the existing history*, not *throw out the latest commits entirely*. Git's command verbs here are tricky. VS probably doesn't use the same verbs, though.

Comment: Questions: 1.) You said "The latest committed version is missing some files". That means that some commit in the history is deleting those files, and it's *after* the commit of yours that added them. Do you see that commit in the history? 2.) When you resetted hard back to your commit that has them, you said you don't see the files in "*Solution* Explorer". Do you see them in "*File* Explorer"? If you never added the files to your solution you won't see them in the default view in VS. There is an option for "Show All Files" in the solution which would display them.